# Use of the package wrapfig

Tags: windows, wrapfig

My aim is to write a text with an image to the right of the text and the text surrounds the image. For this, I read that I should use wrapfig
So in my documentation I wrote: \usepackage{wrapfig}
And as soon as I use this package, I get this error".
! LaTeX Error: File `wrapfig.sty' not found."
even though I installed the package with miktek console.
I am on windows and I code with texmaker:
here is my code:

```
\documentclass[french,12pt,a4paper]{Article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% pour la sortie
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % pour l'entrée
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand{\cRM}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #1}}  % Capital
\newcommand{\cRm}[1]{\textsc{\romannumeral #1}} % Petit majuscule
\newcommand{\crm}[1]{\romannumeral #1}
\newcommand{\siecle}[1]{\cRm{#1}\textsuperscript{e}~siècle}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcoùe to TeX SX! Just in case: in MiKTeX console, the `Tasks` menu has an `update file name database` item. Other than that, if you just want to insert an image, without a caption, you have the ``\InsertBoxR` commaand; from the plain TeX `insbox` package.

Comment: check you updated both user and admin mode in miktex ifyou have both installed